# firstDuplicate issue, need to understand code

Tags: javascript, typescript

Please explain this how it is working. I am not able to understand the code why it is multiplying ?

```
let test1 = [2, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2]
function firstDuplicate(a) {
  for (let i of a) {
    let posi = Math.abs(i) - 1
    if (a[posi] < 0) return posi + 1
    a[posi] = a[posi] * -1
  }

  return -1
}
console.log(firstDuplicate(test1))
```

Comment: What do you think that code is doing?

Comment: for (let i of a) { // for of loop  is running where a is an array and i is its value
let posi = Math.abs(i) - 1 //what ever value is it minus 1 and store in posi
if (a[posi] < 0) return posi + 1 // now why it is using value of an array minus 1 and checking if it is less than 0, next line also don't know why it is there.